# The prime superscript didn't work as derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am really new to Mathematica. I tried a lot of ways but I failed
I am using the Adomian polynomial to decompose a function. The polynomial is generated by:

[image]

Then in my case I need to decompose `f*f''^(2 - n)` and `f` is a function of `η`, so I wrote :

```
terms = 3;
N1[f_] :=  f[η]*f[η]''^(2 - n)  ;

Do[x1[n_] := 1/n!*D[N1[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(i = 0\), \(n\)]\(\((λ^i)\)*
\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(i\)]\)\)], {λ, n}], {n, 0, terms}]
Do[ A1[n_] := Expand[x1[n]] /. λ -> 0, {n, 0, terms}]
```

...then $A_1$ will be

[image]

Then I will give a value of `f0`, assume it is `η^2 /2`
[image]

Clearly, some derivative terms weren't calculated as I wanted since `f` is a function of `η`. I want the derivative to be computed in the output.

Sorry for my bad writing, does anyone have an idea?

---

I appreciated Daniel's answer, but I encounter new questions when I move forward, the series generation is no problem, but when the terms go up to 2, the result will look like
[image]

then my iteration will fail by the term

```
((2 Subscript[f, 2])^\[Prime]\[Prime])[\[Eta]]
```

which looks like
[image]

then Mathematica can't distinguish this term
so it can't sub the value I gave into the equation
how I can deal with it?

Comment: 1. Avoid the use of subscripts.
2. You need to differentiate the function before evaluating it.

Comment: Try`N1[f_] :=  f[η]*D[f[η], {η, 2}]^(2 - n) ` and `Do[x1[n_] := 1/n!*D[N1[Sum[(λ^i)*g[i], {i, 0, n}]], {λ, n}], {n, 0, terms}]`

Comment: To Alan: somebody also told me the first point before, but I really need this to make my equation clearly, because it will become really complicated in my research, I know I can write like f[k_][eta] to have kind of the same function, but if I kept using subscript what I need to pay attention to then?

Comment: To bbgod: It's a good way to replace subscript, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative of a function is written f'[x] and not f[x]'.With this correction and a definition for `Subscript[f, 0]` we get for `A1[1]`:

```
N1[f_] :=  f[η]*f''[η]^(2 - n)  ;
Subscript[f, 0][x_] = x^2/2;
Do[x1[n_] := 1/n!*D[N1[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(i = 0\), \(n\)]\(\((λ^i)\)*
\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(i\)]\)\)], {λ, n}], {n, 0, terms}]
Do[ A1[n_] := Expand[x1[n]] /. λ -> 0, {n, 0, terms}]

A1[1]
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I want !!  thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for your answer a lot!! could you please browse my new problem?

Comment: "n_" is a pattern with name "n". Therefore, you can nor write: "Do[x1[n_] :=...{n,0,terms}". "n_" will not be replaced.